# How do I return more than one value?

Tags: php, html, css, return, echo

I need some help.
I'm not able to use echo because of the structure I've built. I don't have the time to explain why. But my question is, is there any way to return multiple data? lets say this for example:

```
final public function getCamps()
        {
            $campaigns = mysql_query("SELECT * From cms_news WHERE campaign='1'");

            while($skriv = mysql_fetch_assoc($campaigns))
            {
            return
            '
            <hr/> 
            <div class="campaign_images"> 
            </div> 
            <div class="campaign_content"> 
            <b>'.$skriv['title'].'</b><br>
            '.$skriv['shortstory'].'
            </div> 
            <p class="gothere">Go there &raquo;</p> 
            <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
            <hr/> 

            ';
            }

        }
```

But the problem with that is return will only give me 1 value then stop the script. How do I solve this? I've heard that I should return an array or something, but how do I do that? thanks. Sorry for my English btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
final public function getCamps()
    {
        $campaigns = mysql_query("SELECT * From cms_news WHERE campaign='1'");
        $data_return = "";  
        while($skriv = mysql_fetch_assoc($campaigns))
        {
        $data_return .=    //this returns multiple  values from your db
        '
        <hr/> 
        <div class="campaign_images"> 
        </div> 
        <div class="campaign_content"> 
        <b>'.$skriv['title'].'</b><br>
        '.$skriv['shortstory'].'
        </div> 
        <p class="gothere">Go there &raquo;</p> 
        <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
        <hr/> 

        ';
        }
     return($data_return);

    }
```

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! but the return = ""; part gave me an error.

Answer (score 1):

Add the data to an array and return that.

```
$data = array();

while($skriv = mysql_fetch_assoc($campaigns))
{
  $data[] =
  '
  <hr/> 
  <div class="campaign_images"> 
  </div> 
  <div class="campaign_content"> 
  <b>'.$skriv['title'].'</b><br>
  '.$skriv['shortstory'].'
  </div> 
  <p class="gothere">Go there &raquo;</p> 
  <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
  <hr/> 

  ';
}

return $data;
```

If you then just need to output the content then `implode` and `echo`:

```
$data = $obj->getCamps();

echo implode($data);
```

Although personally I wouldn't add the `HTML` in the loop. I'd just add the row data to the array and return that:

```
final public function getCamps()
{

  $data = array();

  $campaigns = mysql_query("SELECT * From cms_news WHERE campaign='1'");

  while($skriv = mysql_fetch_assoc($campaigns))
  {
    $data[] = $skriv;
  }

  return $data;

}
```

And then iterate over the returned array and add the `HTML`:

```
<?php foreach ($obj->getCamps() as $camp) { ?>

  <hr>

  <div class="campaign_images"></div> 

  <div class="campaign_content">

    <b><?php echo $camp['title']; ?></b>

    <br>

    <?php echo $camp['shortstory']; ?>

  </div> 

  <p class="gothere">Go there &raquo;</p> 

  <div style="clear:both;"></div> 

  <hr> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i can't use an echo. I want to print out the data without using echo

Comment: You have to `echo` (or `print`) to output the data.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as a `return` statement executes, control leaves the scope of the function.  You can only ever `return` once.  It looks like what you *want* to do is build a string and return the whole thing.  So instead of this:

```
while(condition) {
    return value;
}
```

Do this:

```
result = '';
while(condition) {
    result .= value;
}
return result;
```

This is a standard pattern for aggregating a result within a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily return an array with multiple key/value pairs. You just have to know how to use it on the receiving end as well.

```
return [
    'html' => '<hr/><div class="campaing_images>....</div>',
    'error' => false,
]
```

You can also just do a normal array index version

```
return [
    '<hr/><div class="campaing_images>....</div>',
    false
]
```